# Infinite rendering of component while fetching data with useEffect hook in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-loop

When i want to fetch collections from api, infinite rendering in useEffect happening  on the console. How can fix it?

```
const Collections = () => {
  const [collections, setCollections] = useState([]);
  const token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  },[setCollections]);
  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://itransition-capstone.herokuapp.com/collections/allCollections",
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        },
      }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setCollections(data);
    console.log("Collections", data);
  };
};
export default Collections;
```

Comment: There is probably no need to use `setCollections` in the dependency array at all, but even that shouldn't trigger recursion, unless you are using `collections` in the dependency array, as then useEffect itself triggers changes to the very dependency it will be watching.

Comment: i put collections as dependency array but didn work :(

Comment: Putting collection in the dependency array will create an infinite cycle because you’re updating the state of collections inside fetchUsers, I would just leave the dependency array empty if you only want to call that endpoint once

Comment: anyway it is re-rendering infinitely. i don know why

Comment: can you check if the line ```console.log("Collections", data);``` is outputting data?

Comment: Does the parent component mount and unmount the Collections component infinitely?